# ios 8 Orientation Issue

Tags: ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, uiinterfaceorientation

my application, developed in iOS7, has a forced orientation base on device:
iphone -> portrait
Ipad -> landscape

With iOS8, if my apps on ipad starts in portrait mode, it will show the app in landscape but the result is:

[image]

How to fix iOS 8 orientation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure if I can answer my own questions, but I have resolved the issue using

```
[self.window setFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```

at the end of `(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`  method.

Comment: You can answer your own questions, and you should if no-one else chimes in with a better answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {



if ([window.rootViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class] ]) {

    if ([[window.rootViewController presentedViewController]
         isKindOfClass:[SignatureViewController class]]) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
    }

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

My issue was related to UIWindows frame which was going in minus. So made the code as below in MyViewController -(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations Method

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];

[self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)];

[appDel.window setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)];
```

Try this.